# Дата последнего изменения цены в opencart 2

Tags: opencart

знатоки! Появилась необходимость узнать дату последнего изменения цены на товар. А также характер самого изменения. Поясню:
Есть приличная номенклатура товаров. Цены и остатки через cron 2 раза в неделю обновляются (через плагин). хочу убедиться в том, что они действительно обновляются. 
То есть хочу узнать по каким товарам произошло изменение стоимости, и, желательно, с какой цены на какую. Но это вторично. Первично - узнать дату последнего обновления цены.

В идеале даже выводить в магазине (на карточке товара) - "Последнее обновление информации о товаре - ##.##.####."

В поиске не нашёл...

Comment: А готовые рабочие варианты тут врятли кто-то выложит? я этого сам точно не сделаю)

Comment: канешн выложит... надо аватарку няшной девочки и много "пажааалстаа". Это же портал бесплатных разрабов. отс.си апворк!

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить поля price_update_date и price_before_update в таблицу product; во время обновления товаров по крону в price_update_date записывать туда временнУю метку а в аблицу price_before_update текущую (ещё не обновлённую) цену на момент обновления товаров. Это позволит без лишних усилий выводить эти данные с товаром.

Если хочется историю изменений для каждого товара - придётся заводить отдельную сущность product_price_history или как-то так.